# How to fix error generated from RSA_public_decrypt function

Tags: c#, c, openssl, libcrypto, openssl-net

I have developed in C under Linux that send a random number to remote pc, then the remote pc read the number and encrypt it with openssl private key (with C# windows application), after that it send, the c program try to decrypt it with its openssl public key as the following:

```
int padding = RSA_PKCS1_PADDING;
RSA_public_decrypt(data_len,enc_data,decrypted,rsa,padding);
```

c#program is developped like this:

```
CryptoKey d = CryptoKey.FromPrivateKey(privateKeyAsPem, null);
RSA rsa = d.GetRSA();
byte[] result = rsa.PrivateEncrypt(code, RSA.Padding.PKCS1);
rsa.Dispose();
```

The problem is I got a random behavior sometimes the C program decrypt without error and sometimes I got the following error:

```
error:04067072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT:padding check failed
```

How to fix this problem?

NOTE:

Keys are generated under Linux like this:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out priv.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
openssl rsa -pubout -in priv.pem -out pub.pem
```

Comment: Typically one would encrypt with the *public key*, why are you doing so with the private key, it may work but there need to be a good reason for doing so? I would guess PrivateEncrypt is actually for signing ...

Comment: The function you are using is for signature operation (and it's pretty low level). Rethink your design and / or edit your question.

Comment: @AlexK.: I can't change private encrypt because it is a need for me, for the problem, this implementation works correctly at about 50% and does not work with the above error at 50%. How can I know the root cause?

Comment: It actually sounds like you are somehow losing padding bytes in the encrypted data from time to time.  You are using a block cipher

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: thanks I'll check

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: your are right, your comment helped me to resolve my problem, thanks

Comment: Glad to help.  Padding problem?

Comment: yes it was a padding problem